# Aftermarket stereo very loud

Tags: electrical, speakers

I just installed a Sony xav-ax1000 in a WK grand Cherokee and it works well except that the volume for the radio is incredibly loud and I will never go beyond 4. I was hoping there is a solution to this. I used a wiring harness that allows the factory amplifier to still be used. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Lower the gain on the factory amp if you can, might also check and see if your headunit has a loudness setting. If all else fails you may just need to bypass the factory amp.